# How do I move a VirtualBox Windows VM from Windows to Mac

Tags: virtualbox

I want to copy a VirtualBox VM from Windows to Mac OS and not sure how to do it.  I have researched online and VirtualBox forums only hit one solution that is for a very old version of VirtualBox.

Likewise checked as below:

One recommendation over at Stack Exchange(https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer) but it's 7-years old, so not something to trust with much newer versions of VirtualBox.

It's a VDI with no snapshots so it's pretty clean.

I tried one of the old solutions just for the heck of it, namely to copy the VDI to the folder on the MAC where indicated to move it in the old posts and Virtualbox errors out that it can't find the VDI.

Comment: What does the manual say, what have you tried so far and how did it fail (if it did)? Wouldn't it be enough to move the VDI file over and load it into VB?

Comment: @nohillside  The Stack Exchange post from 7-years ago doesn't really apply as it's Windows to Windows: "Copy the entire virtual machine folder, containing the .vdi and .vbox files."  Tried it with what appeared to be the equivalent on Mac and got an error that it can't find the VDI.

The VirtualBox Users Guide does not have any info I've found re Windows-to-Mac move VM.  Only found one answer about this that was a match but it's for a very old version of VB (4) and a lot has changed between it and current 6.1.  Hence, reaching out if anyone has done this successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/995193/fatal-could-not-read-from-the-boot-medium-system-halted-in-virtualbox

It's really hard to figure is it superuser or Mac or whatever.

This nailed it.